# How to customize the color of the CheckMark color in android in a dialog. : android

Tags: android

How to customize the color of the CheckMark color in android in a dialog. Currently , By default, the color of the checkmark is green by default. I would like to customize it to a different color of choice

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [styles.xml from android system](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD), you will see that the checkbox style is defined as follows :

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
   <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background</item>
   <item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>
</style>
```

And If you search the resources of the system, you will see that btn_check is a drawable selector with 2 states (on/off) with the check colored green or not.
So if you want to have your own color-drawable, here is what you should do :
- create a styles.xml
- define the 2 drawables to use
- create the xml file supporting the selector

You can find the full documentation quite detailled on [the android google doc.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Hi, I still could not succeed in implementing the solution.

Comment: Can u please help me with a bit more information regarding the same. I have pasted a sample java file for the same. Please help me what exactky i need to do to to have my checkbox color to be changed to some other color instead of red.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder checkbox_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
     DialogCheckBox.this);

         checkbox_dialog.setTitle("Main Title goes here");
   
   checkbox_dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(myitems, choiceitems,
     new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
        boolean isChecked) {
       Log.d("TAG","items getting selected");

      }
     });

Comment: Please edit your first post with this code, this will help next users to find answers to their questions more easily and we will also have a better display with the code styling. You should add your java code, the xml file of your selector to see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To change the checkbox inside a multi-choice dialog, you need a custom adapter for your dialog, so as to have access to the views of the list.
Then, you call method [`setCheckMarkDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#setCheckMarkDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) of class CheckedTextView.

Here is an example:

[image: Alert dialog with custom checkboxes]

File `default_checkbox.xml` inside `res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- checked -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_default" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

File `DialogUtil.java`

```
package example.dialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class DialogUtil {

    private DialogUtil() {
    }

    public static AlertDialog show(Context context) {
        String[] items = {"text 1", "text 2", "text 3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Test")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context, items), null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        ListView list = dialog.getListView();
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        return dialog;
    }

    private static OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("DialogUtil", "Clicked on " + view);
        }
    };

    private static class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] array) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, array);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (view instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                CheckedTextView checkedView = (CheckedTextView) view;
                checkedView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.default_checkbox);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you simply use `AlertDialog`, then before getting the `ListView`, you call `show`, firstly, like explained above.

However, if you use `DialogFragment` and `onCreateDialog`, then you get the `ListView`, inside `onStart`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override checkbox widget styles with modified drawable resources. 
Here is good guide to start with styles/themes http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/