# Scale image inside a checkbox android

Tags: android, view, checkbox

I am changing trying to "fitXY" for my custom image of my CheckBox. I followed the below stackoverflow to understand how to load custom images, the problem is that the full image doesn't appear in the check box. I am looking to `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for the the checkbox image, but I cannot get it to work. (I cannot add that attribute to the checkbox in the xml)

[Changing Default Color of Android CheckBox Check Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302428/changing-default-color-of-android-checkbox-check-mark)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't allow you to use that attribute is that scaleType is an XMLAttribute for ImageView but is not one for CheckBox.  You will need to come up with a different approach.  Perhaps you can embed both a scaled ImageView and your checkBox in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToggleButton instead. After that you can set drawable to its background. The methods of ToggleButton and Checkbox are almost the same.