# Change checkbox color (find the source of the original animation) Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I would like to change checkbox color to blue instead of green (Android 5). I read ([How to change the color of a CheckBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox) and [Changing Default Color of Android CheckBox Check Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302428/changing-default-color-of-android-checkbox-check-mark/11302562#11302562)) that you have to to create a `selector`  and add custom images for checked and unchecked. But i am sure there is must be a way to do this without creating the animation manually. Does anyone know a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lester's answer is correct. But I would like to add more points

```
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/dribbblepink</item>
```

This changes the color of the rectangle/checkbox border

[image]

```
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/green</item>
```

Changes the ripple animation color

[image]

And finally

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
```

[image]

Changes the checkbox color when checked

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of all elements (including checkboxes,edittexts,etc) by adding this lines in your style element:

```
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_color</item>
```