# Android custom CheckedTextView

Tags: android, custom-component, checked

I want to custom the check mark in my several checkedtextview. I wanted to use a "simple" solution, so i did that :

```
    if(serviceChecked.isChecked()){
    serviceChecked.setChecked(false);
    serviceChecked.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
} else {
    serviceChecked.setChecked(true);
    serviceChecked.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_done);
}
```

I've two problems with this solution :

The first is, it's running only the first time, when I check one of my checktextview, uncheck, and check again, my drawable is not visible.

The second problem is, we can see again the "default" checkmarck (the blue)....

How can I resolve it ?

Thx,

Answer (score 4):

Extending the CheckTextBox, you shouldn't need to change the `setCheckMarkDrawable`. Just set it once, and the `setChecked` should appropriately set the checked/non-checked state. Your drawable should be defined in XML, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598098/544198):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- checked -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_default" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: Ok ok, so i can't keep the default "case" and just add my drawable icon to show it's checked ?

Comment: You didn't understand what i said, but it's ok :D I'm going to try your solution, thx :)

Comment: You could just add the drawable, but at that point you'd be doing a really custom CheckTextBox. If you do that, then you want to manage the visibility or swap the icon, not remove it entirely.

Comment: mhhh, i'm not sure to have understand :/ I tried your solution, but the problem is the "default check" is still visible. WHy ?

Comment: The `CheckTextBox` doesn't turn the check mark invisible, but switches the drawables instead. Try a non-checked version of your checkbox.

Comment: I found the problem, i'm stupid (of course) :D it's running, so thx :) but i'm curious to know how to do it with my first "answer"

Comment: You could always just include what your answer is, for future people who might come in.

Comment: I did what you said :)